# How to deal with dead neuron in neural network training?

Tags: neural-networks

This is a homework assignment, so I have strict requirements. In that assignment, I am required to train a neural network with sigmoid activation function to achieve 0 training error rate [I know, wrong thing to do, overfit and such, but I am required to do so :( ].

I have implemented the gradient descent algorithm and things seems fine, but it never reaches 0% training error rate. I diagnosed it a bit and realize all the hidden layer neuron are dead (their output is very close to 0 or 1), so there is no way I can update their weights. The output layer just can't solve the non-linear problem even if their weights can be adjusted.

My questions are:

(1) Is this a well known problem?
(2) How do I deal with it?

I saw some post talking about using a different activation functions, unfortunately that isn't an option for me for this assignment.

Comment: Try initializing the weights with smaller values.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, a different activation function wold be better, but you can't. I would suggest you to try different initializations of the weights: those can affect the final result. You can try a different optizimization technique, too, maybe adding momentum could help you.